# PHP Include path doesn't make sense?

Tags: php

I do not understand this error :

```
Warning: include(): Failed opening '/app/database/alsalemcorpdb.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/app/database/alsalemcorpdb.php') in /var/www/html/index.php on line 4
```

I have now explicitly mentioned the file in include_path, and CHMODed the file to 777.

My code:   `include ("/app/database/alsalemcorpdb.php");`

Any ideas?

Comment: Are u sure the path is correct?

Comment: DON'T mention specific files in the include path..... it's a list of directories, not a list of files

Comment: I have tripple checked the file path, and I have tried with just the directory. Makes no sense?

Comment: try to remove (/) from /app

Comment: You're specifying an absolute filesystem path; suspect you should be using a relative path `include ("app/database/alsalemcorpdb.php");` because you probably don't have a /app folder under your filesystem root, just relative to your webserver root folder

Answer (score 1):

Unless you literally have `/app` as a root-level folder *on the filesystem* (ie. not the domain root), then you should not have a `/` at the beginning of your path.

Instead, try:

```
include("app/database/alsalemcorpdb.php");
```

Comment: You must include the first / if using an absolute path, as I was in this case. Besides, file path errors have a specific error.

Comment: What does `var_dump(file_exists("/app/database/alsalemcorpdb.php"));` give you?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, it turned out to be SELINUX.... It causes this to fail for whatever reason, disabling it fixes the issue.